# Unreal Engine 4 - Math Expression CubeMap to Equirectangular projection shader in Material Editor?

Tags: projection, unreal-engine4, 360-panorama

How can I display a cube texture in an Equirectangular using a material Shader? in Material Editor?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution for months :( 
Cube to Pano. I don't know much about the Material editor